# jQuery how to get element by attribute and value is an variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I defined a variable **comment_id**, it is the value of **comment_id**  attribute of a form tag:

```
var comment_id = '44';
```

so can I insert the value of the variable into the following:

```
$( "div[comment_id = comment_id ]" )
```

so that I can locate the element that. with the attribute value.

I tried something like:

```
$( "div[comment_id = $comment_id ]" )
```

but not work.Any friend can help,I'm a Python guy and I'm very frustrated by JS it is very complicated and need code lots of code to do simple function.

Comment: Try `$(\`div[comment_id="${comment_id}"]\`)`

Comment: Old (ES5) syntax is `$("div[comment_id=" + comment_id + "]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the backtick character instead of the double quote

```
$(`div[comment_id = ${comment_id} ]`)
```